# running mkdir through php using shell script not working

Tags: php, bash, shell, ubuntu-14.04, tty

I have created a file `test.sh` which looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
mkdir /testDir
```

If I run the script on the command line like: `sudo /path/to/test.sh` it successfully creates the directory.

I have added the sudo permissions like this in the `visudo`:

```
www-data ALL=NOPASSWD: /path/to/test.sh
```

and I am running the script like this in my .php file:

```
shell_exec('sh /path/to/test.sh');
```

But no directory is being created!

**What am I doing wrong?!**

---

### Correct user for sudo permissions?

When I run `shell_exec('whoami')` on the php file I get:

```
www-data
```

### Correct path to script from php?

I have tested the shell script by adding an echo statement like:

```
#!/bin/sh
mkdir /testDir
echo "hello"
```

And when I run the `.php` command like:

```
echo shell_exec('sh /path/to/test.sh');
```

the `.php` page returns

> hello

I have also tried in the `test.sh`:

```
output=$( mkdir /testDir )
echo "$output"
```

but nothing is returned

---

## Update

If I add this to the `visudo`:

```
www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

**it works!!** But when I do:

```
www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /path/to/test.sh
```

It doesn't... As you know already know.

---

I have found a good way to debug by also changing the PHP to

```
echo shell_exec('sh /path/to/test.sh  2>&1 1> /dev/null');
```

and it returns the error:

> sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified

So I have tried:

- adding `Defaults:www-data !requiretty` to the `visudo` but no luck!!!!
- adding `-t` and `-A` to the sudo command... (ie `sudo -t ...`)
- adding `export SUDO_ASKPASS=/usr/lib/openssh/gnome-ssh-askpass` before the sudo command and that then just leads to a whole new world of errors.

I have no idea about this `requiretty` as it does not seem to be anywhere on my ubuntu system. It is not mentioned once in the `visudo`?

---

## I have spent too long on this!

Can someone tell me what the problems that I could come across if I did just do:

```
www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

?

Comment: Have you looked in other places, like the webserver root for the `/testDir/? It may be `chroot` so that `/` isn't really `/`.  This could be time for an `updatedb` and `locate`

Comment: I want it to be the root folder. I tried `sudo find / -name "testDir"` but no luck

Comment: Does the `mkdir` report success?  If that's in a shell script you should be able to do an `echo $?` after to see its return value, or put it in an `if` statement to get something meaningful from it.

Comment: Hmm, it occurs to me that though you're giving sudo permission to execute the script, that doesn't mean that user will have write permission to `/` so you may also want to check that.

Comment: but doesn't sudo have write permissions everywhere?

Comment: yeah, I think you're right. . . do you have selinux or something similar running?  It may be preventing web processes from running outside their typical areas

Comment: No I don't... Have you seen my edit? So strange!

Comment: Hello try to change #!/bin/sh  to #!/bin/bash

Comment: Is it working from console? `su www-data -s /bin/bash` and `php -f phpfile.php`

Comment: @take `su www-data -s /bin/bash` asks for password which does not exist. Yes it works when I do `php -f phpfile.php` (without sudo may I add from root user)

Comment: If you su from `root` there souldn't be a password request. and of course, after su'ing to www-data, it should be `sudo php -f phpfile.php`

Comment: Okay so I have 'logged in' to `su www-data -s /bin/bash` and when I do `sudo php -f phpfile.php` it asks for a password (which I don't have)?

Comment: Note you are running `sh /path/to/test.sh` from php, which is different from the `/path/to/test.sh` you added in sudoers or even `/bin/sh /path/to/test.sh` that was suggested. What if you say `/bin/sh /path/to/test.sh` in your php script and add `www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/sh /path/to/test.sh` in your sudoers? That is, use the exact same syntax, otherwise sudoers won't accept it.

Comment: @fedorqui done exactly that and no luck

Comment: I would also try with `www-data ALL = NOPASSWD: ...`, that is, without the `(ALL)`.

Comment: Not working :( aghh so weird!!

Answer (score 1):

If

```
www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

works, but

```
www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /path/to/test.sh
```

does not, then clearly the executed command does not match `/path/to/test.sh`.
And looking at your code, you are actually *not* invoking `/path/to/test.sh`:

```
sh /path/to/test.sh
```

You are invoking `sh`! With `/path/to/test.sh` as first argument, but still.
You either need to invoke the script directly (if that works):

```php
shell_exec('/path/to/test.sh');
```

or update your sudoers file accordingly (note the *full* path of `sh`):

```
www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/sh /path/to/test.sh
```

Comment: Unfortunately neither removing `sh` from `shell_exec()` or adding `/bin/sh` to the `visudo` are working!!!

Comment: Could you try to insert a `while true; do true; done;` into your shell script, then run the PHP script as `www-data` and use `ps aux | grep www-data` to find what your full script path actually looks like?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me: Added this to my ubuntu > sudoers file `www-data ALL=/etc/path-to-my/script.sh`

Hope this solves yours too

Answer (score 0):

Some tips I would try:

- try using exec instead of shell_exec
- try disabling selinux if enabled
- try to remove the /bin/sh prefix and use the shebang inside the script instead
- become www-data (su www-data -s /bin/bash) and do your tests on the CLI

I hope this helps